# Fresh install of debian, Can't get apache to work

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

I had to reinstall Debian. Before the reinstall I have been using my server as a file share (using Owncloud). After an reinstalling Debian on a freshly formatted drive and installing apache2 I have been unable to get the default page to show up.

Apache service is running:

```
    ● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-08-08 14:39:45 UTC; 10min ago
  Process: 2571 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2597 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─2613 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2617 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2618 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2619 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2620 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─2621 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Aug 08 14:39:44 raspberrypi apache2[2597]: Starting web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally ...ress this message
Aug 08 14:39:45 raspberrypi apache2[2597]: .
Aug 08 14:39:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If i run `apache2 -t` this is what I get:

```
    [Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.502453 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.502855 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.502892 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.502966 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.595580 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.596803 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Aug 08 14:52:00.596883 2016] [core:warn] [pid 2753] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00543: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

if I run `netstat -tap` I get this:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1017/mysqld
tcp        0      0 *:webmin                *:*                     LISTEN      1413/perl
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      538/sshd
tcp        0     64 raspberrypi.home:ssh    static-xxx-xx-xx-:59984 ESTABLISHED 2011/sshd: pi [priv
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      2613/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      538/sshd
```

My apache user and group are set to `www-data:www-data`

Update:

All traffic over http is working but it doesn't even try to connect over https, nothing is showing up in the logs and port 443 is open in both iptables and my router

Comment: `netstat` output shows that your apache is listening only in IPv6 address. Try to find `Listen` directive in apache config and set it to listen on every port.

Comment: @PavelKazhevets supposedly meant "on every IP".  Well, in any case I'm inclined to think that's not the case: on by Debian Jessie system apache listens on this wildcard IPv6 interface while my system only has IPv4 connectivity -- the kernel takes care of this automatically.

Comment: I changed it and i still have the same problem:
("tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      5568/apache2")

Comment: The first thing to check is to install `netcat` or `telnet`, connect to port 80 and issue (literally): `GET / HTTP/1.0` then hit the Enter key twice and see whether Apache returns something back. By "connect" I mean typing `nc localhost 80` or `telnet localhost 80`.

Comment: that command does nothing for me

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly does it nothing? It should either fail with an error explaining it was unable to connect (unlikely) or just wait for your input -- which should have been as I've described. IOW, either of those commands connects directly to the HTTP server's port. HTTP servers don't "greet" their clients in any way -- they expect a HTTP request to come in from them on each new connection, and performing such a request is what I've asked you to do.

Comment: You can study a few top links from [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=testing+http+server+telnet) to get the idea of what I'm asking. SO comments are unfit for lengthy explanations anyway.

Comment: Oh, and please refer to a person whose comment you're replying to using `@nick` notation -- otherwise they won't ge notified about your answer when they move away from your question / close the SO page.

Comment: @kostix Sorry, i didn't realize i needed to reply like that. it didn't recognize the command, but if i'm reading this correctly this should test the same thing as typing wget http://127.0.0.1/ -O - into ssh and that does connect for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43660/discussion-between-kostix-and-thestarvinggeek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out:

The problem was that the ssl module wasn't enabled in apache2. To enable it I had to:

type `a2enmod ssl` and hit enter then type `service apache2 restart` hit enter

and it worked